# Using i18n in component text property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization, components

Looking for a advice/hint for following "problem" where I created a component in nuxt.js like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="mx-auto max-w-screen-md text-center mb-8 lg:mb-12">
    <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900">
      {{ textHeader }}
    </h2>
    <p class="mb-5 font-light text-gray-500 sm:text-xl">
      {{ textSubHeader }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'HeaderAndSubheader',
  props: {
    textHeader: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    textSubHeader: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script
```

Pretty simple and straight forward. So means if you're using this component, you're injecting the text prop in the HTML element like this:

```
<ContentHeaderAndSubHeader textHeader="This is the title" textSubHeader="This is the subtitle" />
```

It works expected and no issues about that so far.

Only one problem which occures: i18n

Since the content should be support locales, I do looking for a way to solve that.

My approach was to work with `computed` in the file, where you make use of this component, like that as an example:

```
<ContentHeaderAndSubHeader textHeader="{{ content.textHeader }}" textSubHeader="{{ content.textSubHeader }}" />
```

script section looks like this:

```
computed: {
    content() {
      return {
        textHeader: this.$t('title.content'),
        textSubHeader: this.$t('subtiitle.content'),
      };
    },
  },
```

Of course it won't work but how I'm able to inject content from the `computed` method into the `textHeader=""` and `textSubHeader` elements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's `:textHeader="content.textHeader"`. Is there any other problem with this?